# php tidy none break space

Tags: php, tidy

I have an html with some special html chars like `&nbsp;` ... but tidy make `�` for this character as space.

```
// tidy config
$tidyConfig = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'output-xhtml' => true,
    'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'show-body-only' => true,
    'fix-backslash' => true,
    'quote-marks' => true,
    'wrap' => 1024,
);

// tidy up
$string = (string)tidy_parse_string($string, $tidyConfig);
```

what's option must be set or change.

result http://codepad.viper-7.com/bsqD0n

Comment: Did you try replacing `&nbsp;` with space before you run `tidy` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols any better way for tidy?

Comment: Check your input encoding: Is it really utf-8?

Comment: @madflow yeah you can try http://codepad.viper-7.com/bsqD0n

Comment: Nice debug tool. But I have no idea ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?
http://codepad.viper-7.com/B5PDFc

> bare  Top Type: Boolean Default: no Example: y/n, yes/no, t/f,
>   true/false, 1/0
>   This option specifies if Tidy should strip Microsoft
>   specific HTML from Word 2000 documents, and **output spaces rather than
>   non-breaking spaces where they exist in the input**.

```
$string = 'word word &nbsp; word';

// tidy config
$tidyConfig = array(
    'indent' => true,
    'output-xhtml' => false,
    'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
    'show-body-only' =>true,
    'fix-backslash' => true,
    'quote-marks' => true,
    'wrap' => 1024,
    'bare' => true,
);

// tidy up
var_dump((string)tidy_parse_string($string, $tidyConfig));
```

*The output-xhtml (false) is something I experimented with, but it makes no difference regarding the output (in this case)